# $\iff$ vs $\implies$ in simple set theory exercise proof of $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is about justifying $\implies$ vs $\iff$ in a proof step.

Proving that $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$ is a common exercise, myself I am doing it as part of Tao's Analysis I 4th-ed ex 3.1.18.

The first step is uncontroversial, simply applying the definitions of union and intersection.

$$x \in (A \cap (A \cup B)) \iff (x \in A) \land ((x \in A) \lor (x \in B))$$

This (RHS of above) tells us the following two statements are **both** true:

- $(x \in A)$
- $(x \in A) \lor (x \in B)$

Both statements are only true when $(x \in A)$. Thus

$$x \in (A \cap (A \cup B)) \iff (x \in A)$$

This would let us conclude $A \cap (A \cup B)=A$, but many example proofs instead have one-way **implication** not bidirectional **iff**, thus requiring the converse to be proven too in the usual way.

$$x \in (A \cap (A \cup B)) \implies (x \in A)$$

**Question -** where is the error in using $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ ?

---

**UPDATE2 - further thoughts**

If following two statements must **both** be true:

- $(x \in A)$
- $(x \in A) \lor (x \in B)$

Can we say "Both statements are true **if and only if** $(x \in A)$"?

If yes, then we can naturally say $x \in (A \cap (A \cup B)) \iff (x \in A)$.

Comment: Please fix the title. (Didn't you see that before posting?)

Comment: In this specific case you are right: both statements are true when $x \in A$. But, in general, to prove $S=T$ regarding sets, you have to prove that $S \subseteq T$ AND $T \subseteq S$.

Comment: AFAIK, this a close to a matter of opinion. You are plain right, everything could be done through equivalences (iif). But what actually matters is to demonstrate one direction, so some authors prefere to use $\implies$ instead of $\iff$.

Comment: hi @MauroALLEGRANZA - as a self-teaching student I am aware that the standard pattern is to prove both $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$. However in some cases this doesn't seem to be required, and I think the example in the question is one of them. So I could follow the many online sample answers but I want to deepen my understanding and hence my question. I appreciate your giving time to help.

Comment: Minor comment: be more careful with pronouns. In your sentence "**This** tells us the following two statements are both true...", one does not know the antecedent of **This** (I believe your intention was to refer to the right hand side of the previous $\iff$ statement).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful tautology: $$P \land (P \lor Q) \iff P$$

You can apply this tautology in proofs just like you apply other tautologies such as the [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

There is no error whatsoever in doing that.